# SQL Query: Unable to get the count of values between a time stamp from multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider the below tables

Table 1:

```
id  instance    ttime               val

1   -1      29-5-2915 08:17:29      2000
2   -1      29-5-2915 09:17:29      2938
3   -1      29-5-2915 10:17:29      2837
4   inst1   29-5-2915 11:17:29      1233
5   inst2   29-5-2915 12:17:29      2837
```

Table 2:

```
id  instance    ttime               val

1   -1      29-5-2915 13:17:29      10
2   -1      29-5-2915 14:17:29      29
3   -1      29-5-2915 15:17:29      283
4   inst1   29-5-2915 16:17:29      123
5   inst2   29-5-2915 17:17:29      28
```

I want the total count of ids between 29-5-2915 08:17:29 and  29-5-2915 17:17:29.

How do I write the join query to get my expected output?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I don't get it. You want to count the ids. So is the count in this case 10 or a distinct count of 4?

Comment: Yes Arion, my results should be like, id = 10. (count total ids from a particular time period, in the given example start time is 29-5-2915 08:17:29 and end time is 29-5-2915 17:17:29   )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT count(*)
(
   SELECT id FROM Table1 
   WHERE ttime BETWEEN '29-5-2915 08:17:29' AND '29-5-2915 17:17:29'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT id FROM Table2
   WHERE ttime BETWEEN '29-5-2915 08:17:29' AND '29-5-2915 17:17:29'
) AS t
```

Or if you want a distinct count:

```
SELECT count(*)
(
   SELECT id FROM Table1 
   WHERE ttime BETWEEN '29-5-2915 08:17:29' AND '29-5-2915 17:17:29'
   UNION
   SELECT id FROM Table2
   WHERE ttime BETWEEN '29-5-2915 08:17:29' AND '29-5-2915 17:17:29'
) AS t
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply dude... I want to get a total count of ids from both the tables....In your query there is no time stamp 29-5-2915 08:17:29 in the second table...'My expectation is, wanna get a total count of data between 29-5-2915 08:17:29 and 29-5-2915 08:17:29 '..

Comment: @Tester : Then just change the between statement

Answer (score 0):

To get the count for one table you could do:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Table1
WHERE 
    ttime > '29-5-2915 08:17:29' AND 
    ttime < '29-5-2915 17:17:29'
```

You could do that for both table and sum it up:

```
SELECT sum(count)
FROM (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM Table1
    WHERE 
        ttime > '29-5-2915 08:17:29' AND 
        ttime < '29-5-2915 17:17:29'
    UNION
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM Table2
    WHERE 
        ttime > '29-5-2915 08:17:29' AND 
        ttime < '29-5-2915 17:17:29'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

select sum(count) from (select count(id) from table1 where ttime between '29-5-2915 08:17:29 ' and '29-5-2915 17:17:29' 
union all
 select count(id) from table2 where ttime between '29-5-2915 08:17:29 ' and '29-5-2915 17:17:29' ) as test;

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
     select t1.id,count(*) as countfrom table1 
     join table2 on t1.id = t2.id 
     and (t1.ttime between '29-5-2915 08:17:29'  and '29-5-2915 17:17:29')
     and (t2.ttime between '29-5-2915 08:17:29' and '29-5-2915 17:17:29')
     group by t1.id
```

Comment: Joining of the tables is not what the OP is about